# Render all markdown cells in a Jupyter notebook at once

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a convenient way to render all markdown cells in a Jupyter notebook at once without running the code cells?

I find it quite annoying that while moving through my notebook and doing some little corrections the markdown cells "loose" their formatting. Is there an extension or a command with which I can "run" (i.e. render) all and only the markdown cells? If not, is there a way to at least update the table of content from the markdown cells. My table of content is realized via `nbextensions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which provides a `Render all Markdown cells` action if you are not limited to plain Jupyter notebooks. Doing this programmatically within the notebook seems to be not trivial to do as we can derive from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3101). We might be able to implement this ourselves, but I am not aware of any resources that provide something similar.

[image]

Comment: [RetroLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/retrolab) has `Render All Markdown Cells` under the `Run` menu too if you need something closer to the classic notebook look. You can try it right in your browser by clicking [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/jtpio/4a6a34da66b32249e28df718ec30e4d7/master?urlpath=/retro/notebooks/tour.ipynb). The next version of the classic Jupyter Notebook will run on similar underlying machinery as JupyterLab, along the lines of RetroLab, & so I wonder if some of these abilities will be more easily be exposable/customizable in the classic interface when that happens.

Comment: Thank you, David. Switching to Jupyterlab is a solution that works for me. Just a few remarks for all who are using (as me) Anaconda and have installed it some time ago. First update Anaconda via ``conda update --all`` that gives you the latest Jupyterlab installation and ensures that it is properly embedded in your environment. After this everything should work fine. My environments with the adequate kernels for Pytorch and all my notebooks worked immediately.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I'm glad that it works now!